# AmbiguousResolutionException when deploying WAR

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy

I am getting a weird error at deploy to WildFly 8.2.1, something to do with Resteasy and maven setup. I've lost countless hours googling around to no avail.
-Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
-AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001318: Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between

Project organisation:

```
-root  
-project  
--project-ear
--project-main
--project-rest
--project-jms
```

**root pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>si.fri.liis.jmsprojekt</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-all</artifactId>
                <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
                <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <version>7</version>
                        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                        <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
                        <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                        <clientIncludes>
                            <clientInclude>si/fri/liis/jmsprojekt/**/*SbRemote.class</clientInclude>
                            <clientInclude>si/fri/liis/jmsprojekt/**/*SbLocal.class</clientInclude>
                            <clientInclude>si/fri/liis/jmsprojekt/**/*Data.class</clientInclude>
                            <clientInclude>si/fri/liis/jmsprojekt/**/*Exception.class</clientInclude>
                        </clientIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <warName>jmsprojekt</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**project pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>si.fri.liis.jmsprojekt</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../root/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>jmsprojekt</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>jmsprojekt-ear</module>
        <module>jmsprojekt-main</module>
        <module>jmsprojekt-jms</module>
        <module>jmsprojekt-rest</module>
    </modules>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>si.fri.liis.jmsprojekt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmsprojekt-main</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>si.fri.liis.jmsprojekt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmsprojekt-main</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb-client</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>si.fri.liis.jmsprojekt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmsprojekt-jms</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>si.fri.liis.jmsprojekt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmsprojekt-rest</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**ear pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>si.fri.liis.jmsprojekt</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmsprojekt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>jmsprojekt-ear</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>si.fri.liis.jmsprojekt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmsprojekt-main</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>si.fri.liis.jmsprojekt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmsprojekt-rest</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>si.fri.liis.jmsprojekt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmsprojekt-jms</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**rest pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>si.fri.liis.jmsprojekt</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmsprojekt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>jmsprojekt-rest</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>si.fri.liis.jmsprojekt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmsprojekt-main</artifactId>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**WildFly deployment log, too long to paste:**
http://pastebin.com/NK4eaba1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your linked log, it looks like you are including `resteasy` twice and it might be coming from your "rest pom.xml".  It looks like the dependency on `resteasy` there is probably defaulting to `compile` scope. Same with the dependency on `java-ee`.  These should both be `provided` scope.

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001318: Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between:
>     - Managed Bean [class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBXmlSeeAlsoProvider] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
>     - Managed Bean [class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBXmlSeeAlsoProvider] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

Comment: I think this might be it. I set provided scope on all projects and it seems to work now. I'll wait a day to accept the answer just in case tho, I don't trust maven. :)

Comment: I think you can trust maven.  I personally prefer Gradle. It is important to remember (or determine) what you container provided because issues like this can crop up. WildFly attempts to figure out what you application needs from its implicit modules. This [page](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments) may provide some insight.